# Callback when a periodic task is cancelled and done

Tags: java

I have two tasks: The first task (`work`) is reoccurring and the second task (`cleanup`) is releases some resources.  The `cleanup` task should be run exactly once after the reoccurring `work` task has completed and will not be run again.

My first instinct was something like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = ...;
ScheduledFuture<?> future = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(work, ...);

// other stuff happens

future.cancel(false);
cleanup.run();
```

The problem here is that `cancel()` returns immediately.  So if `work` happens to be running, then `cleanup` will overlap it.

Ideally I would use something like Guava's `Futures.addCallback(ListenableFuture future, FutureCallback callback)`.  (Guava 15 may have [something like that](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableScheduledFuture.html)).

In the meantime, how can fire a callback when `future` is cancelled *and* `work` no longer running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that I've come up with.  It seems to be pretty simple, but I still assume there's a more common and/or elegant solution out there.  I'd really like to see one in a library like Guava...

First I create a wrapper to impose mutual exclusion on my Runnables:

```
private static final class SynchronizedRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Object monitor;
    private final Runnable delegate;

    private SynchronizedRunnable(Object monitor, Runnable delegate) {
        this.monitor = monitor;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            delegate.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I create a wrapper to fire my callback on successful invokations of `cancel`:

```
private static final class FutureWithCancelCallback<V> extends ForwardingFuture.SimpleForwardingFuture<V> {

    private final Runnable callback;

    private FutureWithCancelCallback(Future<V> delegate, Runnable callback) {
        super(delegate);
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            boolean cancelled = super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
            if (cancelled) {
                callback.run();
            }
            return cancelled;
    }
}
```

Then I roll it all together in my own method:

```
private Future<?> scheduleWithFixedDelayAndCallback(ScheduledExecutorService service, Runnable work, long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit, Runnable cleanup) {

    Object monitor = new Object();

    Runnable monitoredWork = new SynchronizedRunnable(monitor, work);

    Runnable monitoredCleanup = new SynchronizedRunnable(monitor, cleanup);

    Future<?> rawFuture = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(monitoredWork, initialDelay, delay, unit);

    Future<?> wrappedFuture = new FutureWithCancelCallback(rawFuture, monitoredCleanup);

    return wrappedFuture;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it another shot then. Either you may enhance the command or you may wrap the executed `Runnable`/`Callable`. Look at this:

```
public static class RunnableWrapper implements Runnable {

    private final Runnable original;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public RunnableWrapper(Runnable original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public void run() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            this.original.run();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void awaitTermination() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

So you can change your code to

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = ...;
RunnableWrapper wrapper = new RunnableWrapper(work);
ScheduledFuture<?> future = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(wrapper, ...);

// other stuff happens

future.cancel(false);
wrapper.awaitTermination();
cleanup.run();
```

After calling `cancel`, either `work` is no longer running and `awaitTermination()` returns immediately, or it is running and `awaitTermination()` blocks until it's done.

Comment: Your solution is pretty much the same as mine.  I accepted my solution only because it's more "fire and forget" from the client's standpoint.   That's a nice property for my particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do

```
// other stuff happens

future.cancel(false);
service.shutdown();
service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
cleanup.run();
```

This will tell your executor service to shutdown, thus allowing you to wait for the possibly running `work` to be finished.

Comment: I don't want to cancel all the tasks in the executor service... just the one I scheduled.  In fact the ScheduledExecutorService is provided to me and I don't know who else is submitting tasks to it.

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate... that rules out extending the `ScheduledExecutorService` as well, where you'd have more options. What about your `work` instance? Is that in your hands?

Comment: Yes, the work and cleanup tasks/Runnables are mine. I'd like to separate the threading/executor concerns from the business logic in work/cleanup... but I'd be happy to have these classes inherit from some Task, or I can wrap them in some other runnable/callable class.

Comment: Well, have a look at my second answer then. ;)